# Why does a second subscription change the outcome of my stream?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

The following code works as expected (see output):

```js
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { scan } from "rxjs/operators";
export type ColumnFilter = { field: string, value: string };

let sub$: Subject<ColumnFilter> = new Subject<ColumnFilter>();
let obs$: Observable<ColumnFilter[]> = new Observable<ColumnFilter[]>();

obs$ = sub$.pipe(
    scan((acc: ColumnFilter[], curr) => {
        const index = acc.findIndex(f => f.field === curr.field);
        if (index === -1) {
            acc.push({ field: curr.field, value: curr.value });
            return acc;
        }

        curr.value === '' ?
            acc.splice(index, 1) :
            acc[index] = { field: curr.field, value: curr.value };
        return acc;
    }, [])
);


obs$.subscribe(
    value => console.log(value)
);

sub$.next({ field: 'size', value: 'xl' })
sub$.next({ field: 'color', value: 'black' })
sub$.next({ field: 'color', value: '' })


// output:
//    [ { field: 'size', value: 'xl' } ]
//    [ { field: 'size', value: 'xl' }, { field: 'color', value: 'black' } ]
//    [ { field: 'size', value: 'xl' } ]
```

Now if I add a second Subscription to the `obs$` observable, the output changes: (Check the last value of the stream. It now contains `{ field: 'color', value: '' }`)

```js
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { scan } from "rxjs/operators";
export type ColumnFilter = { field: string, value: string };


let sub$: Subject<ColumnFilter> = new Subject<ColumnFilter>();
let obs$: Observable<ColumnFilter[]> = new Observable<ColumnFilter[]>();

obs$ = sub$.pipe(
    scan((acc: ColumnFilter[], curr) => {
        const index = acc.findIndex(f => f.field === curr.field);
        if (index === -1) {
            acc.push({ field: curr.field, value: curr.value });
            return acc;
        }

        curr.value === '' ?
            acc.splice(index, 1) :
            acc[index] = { field: curr.field, value: curr.value };
        return acc;
    }, [])
);

// vvv this was added
obs$.subscribe()
// ^^^ this was added

obs$.subscribe(
    value => console.log(value)
);

sub$.next({ field: 'size', value: 'xl' })
sub$.next({ field: 'color', value: 'black' })
sub$.next({ field: 'color', value: '' })

// output:
//    [ { field: 'size', value: 'xl' } ]
//    [ { field: 'size', value: 'xl' }, { field: 'color', value: 'black' } ]
//    [ { field: 'size', value: 'xl' }, { field: 'color', value: '' } ]
```

I don't understand why the second subscription is changing the outcome of the stream. I can only guess it has something to do with mutating the accumulator? Because if I use `acc.filter` instead of `acc.splice`, it works as expected.

**Edit**

Added a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6-opeartors-uzojgw?file=index.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what happens in your second sample code: When an event is triggered by `sub$.next()`, the pipe is executed once for each subscribed observable. Since the `acc: ColumnFilter[]` of the `scan` operator is shared between these executions, the described side effects occur.

My suggestion is to use either the `share` or `shareReplay` operator so that the pipe is executed only once per event and the values emitted by the pipe are multicasted for the subscribers (= all subscribers get the same object reference).

```js
obs$ = sub$.pipe(
  scan((acc: ColumnFilter[], curr) => {
    const index = acc.findIndex((f) => f.field === curr.field);
    if (index === -1) {
      acc.push({ field: curr.field, value: curr.value });
      return acc;
    }

    curr.value === ''
      ? acc.splice(index, 1)
      : (acc[index] = { field: curr.field, value: curr.value });
    return acc;
  }, []),
  share() // you might use shareReplay(1) instead, e.g. if you have late subscribers
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The accumulator of the `scan` operator is shared, so every subscription will have a effect on the others.

If you down't want that behaviour, make a new observable everytime :

```
const newObs = () =>
  sub$.pipe(
    scan((acc: ColumnFilter[], curr) => {
      const index = acc.findIndex((f) => f.field === curr.field);
          if (index === -1) {
            acc.push({ field: curr.field, value: curr.value });
            return acc;
          }
      
          curr.value === ''
            ? acc.splice(index, 1)
            : (acc[index] = { field: curr.field, value: curr.value }); */
      acc.push(curr);
      return acc;
    }, [])
  );

newObs().subscribe();
```